# Is there a way of adjusting the screen brightness programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone app for photographic purposes (kind of a lightbox). This app needs as much brightness as possible. Is there a way to change the screen brightness programmatically, and then restore it back some time later?

Answer (score 78):

Edit: iOS 5 now includes a [screen brightness API](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006903-CH3-SW19).

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.5];
```

Previous answer:

No, this capability is not exposed via public APIS.

Edit: Note that a future possible iOS release may or may not have screen brightness on the multitasking bar on one particular iDevice.

Comment: While I too can't say whether that is the case or not due to a certain agreement I have regarding the disclosure of proprietary information... it is certainly the case that the major third-party "reader" apps contain brightness sliders. So whether or not it's exposed, people are doing it, and it's flying with the app store reviewers.

Comment: They're adjusting the colours of the background of the text, not the actual screen brightness.

Comment: Kudos to you for coming back to your answer a year later and updating it :)

Comment: Any way to automatically unset the screen brightness? (revert to user's previous settings?) Or do I just have to keep track of that?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but your app will most likely get rejected from the App Store, because it uses a private API.
A flashlight-app was rejected because it adjusted the screen brightness, so I wouldn't recommend it.

> In iOS 4.2, the iPad will have a
>   screen brightness-adjuster in the
>   multitasking-bar,

(as mentioned by @coob) so you could tell your users to set the brightness there.

---

What you could do, is to create a black overlay-view, and set it's alpha to more or less, according to how bright you want the screen to be. This won't actually make the screen less/more bright, but it will give the user an illusion of that.

Comment: only the iPad, or also the iPhone?

Comment: Only on the iPad, unfortunately.

Comment: NOTE: This answer is now obsolete; there is a public API since iOS 5.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Swift answer to this question.

```
import UIKit
extension UIScreen
{
    static func setMainBrightness(brightness: CGFloat)
    {
        guard (0...1).contains(brightness) else
        {
            print("Attempt to set the screen brightness to an invalid value: \(brightness) should be between 0 and 1 inclusive.")
            return
        }
        self.main.brightness = brightness
    }
}
```

Call it by using:

```
UIScreen.setMainBrightness(0.5)
```

Or ignore my extension (which I just wrote to illustrate the limits) and just call:

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = 0.5
```

Comment: current (3.1) Swift: `UIScreen.main.brightness = 1.0`