# For iPhone brightness set through slider control in my iPhone applications programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a way of adjusting the screen brightness programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779667/is-there-a-way-of-adjusting-the-screen-brightness-programmatically)

I am new to Stack Overflow and its my first question in this forum. I have researched many times but I can't get a proper answer for this question.

I want to put one slider in my applications is for iPhone and for iPad both which slider adjust the iPhone brightness; means increase and decrease the iPhone brightness.

So how can it be possible this through programmatically. I just want some idea that is it possible or not and how.

Give me guidance as I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This has been answered previously on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779667/is-there-a-way-of-adjusting-the-screen-brightness-programmatically

Answer (score 7):

refer a following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,40)];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.f;
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0f;
    slider.value = [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness];
    [[self view]addSubview:slider];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)sliderHandler:(UISlider *)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"value:%f", sender.value);
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:sender.value];
}
```

Comment: Okay but thats not working in my case. i have done that but not working.

Comment: not working? or working but you don't want it? I tested. working fine. what's the problem? are you really tried?

Comment: yes i   tried plz tell me how it can be done ?

Comment: check out this my test project: [Brightness_Test](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-ea81e71b.html) this project. same above code.

Comment: I so glad to hear. my answer accept please ^^; my answer left clicked "v" button

Comment: @bitmapdata.com Isn't that "v" button for downvote?